# SQL Server 2008R2 Standard or Web Edition for heavy IIS usage

Tags: iis, sql-server-2008, limitations

Currently our client is running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Edition and had hit the 4GB capped. We need to provide a solution to them and I notice there are two option(as topic) for them now.

The application will use the database intensively and there's an Time Management System running too. Data need to be inserted every 30 minutes and all the while there will be users using the ASP.Net application. Automated process is also running from time to time in the Web Service too.

And I notice the "Number of CPU" limitation in SQL Server, does it mean "1 CPU" equal to "1 Physical Processor"? or does it mean "1 Core in 1 Physical Processor"? or "multi-core in 1 Physical Processor"?

So can anyone give me more details and advises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution: Upgrade to R2. The 4gb cap was raised to 10gb there. WHOOW ;)

Second solution: Web edition, rented. Costs little money per month under SPLA, and a public web application accounts as service provider.

> And I notice the "Number of CPU" limitation in SQL Server, does it mean "1 CPU" equal to "1
>   Physical Processor"?

MS never went in to the stupid craziness of playing games here. 1 Processor = 1 physical socket.

Have the customer sign up as service provider under SPLA.

Comment: Beside SPLA, can customer purchase the license?

Comment: Why should they be so stupid to do that? SPLA is cheaper AND includes all updates. AND it is scalable - you can add / remove licenses every month as you need. Purchasing is outright stupid from a financial and business side for 99% of the customers.

Comment: @tomtom - your SPLA advice is misinformed. Unless you're a web hoster AND a MS partner then you can't buy SPLA licenses (See "How do I know I am eligible for SPLA?" - [SPLA Program Benefits](http://www.microsoft.com/hosting/en/us/licensing/splabenefits.aspx)). @foo0110 's customer will most likely not be eligible, I suspect @foo0110 isn't either. My advice would be (if this server is hosted) to find a SPLA reseller/hoster (they usually all are if they're doing this legit). Otherwise if this is self hosted then the customer *will* need to buy a regular license.

Comment: Ah, no, go back to basic school and learn reading. MS partner is "sign up, finished" (not gold partner) and as long as it is a service people use it is legit. In this case: Time management that gets paid for (service) -> spla. Time Manamagnet for a company internally - no spla. That said, 10gb is a LOT for internal compqany time management, and large companies (10k+ employees) have licenses automatically pretty much, so the assumption this is a service (time management website) is legit. This would mean SPLA is valid.

Comment: @tomtom - I work for a webhoster and we are both a MS partner and a SPLA reseller. You are factually wrong. MS Partner is not "sign up, finished", there's a bit more work than that. There are even more hurdles just to become a SPLA reseller, also on top of that you need proper record keeping and keep up to date with your license usage submissions. You are very misinformed.

Comment: Being SPLA partner myself - it IS "sign up, finished". You dont need anything mor ethan basic partnership for SPLA. I am there. Dont tell people the wrong stuff. Now, customer usage is a lot harder for someone like you than a service provider who does not resell ;)

Comment: @TomTom this mean the customer will have to purchase Standard Edition? Correct me if i'm wrong, i'm still new to these licensing thing.